# How to create a react functional component from a standard javascript element

Tags: javascript, jsx

and thanks for reading. I never learned about the bridge that 'connects but separates' Javascript and JSX. How do i convert a javascript html component into a react component, as attempted at the bottom.

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div id="tradingview_ae2c6"></div>
    <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new TradingView.widget(
  {
            "width": 980,
        "height": 610,
        "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
        "interval": "D",
        "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
        "theme": "Light",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "en",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": false,
        "allow_symbol_change": true,
        "container_id": "tradingview_ae2c6"
      }
        );
  </script>
</div>
```

convert that into this

```
import React from 'react'
import * as TradingView from 'https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js'

export default function Api() {
    const options = {
        "width": 980,
        "height": 610,
        "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
        "interval": "D",
        "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
        "theme": "Light",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "en",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": false,
        "allow_symbol_change": true,
        "container_id": "tradingview_ae2c6"
    }
    const chart = new TradingView.widget({ options })
    return (
        <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
            {chart}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What does TradingView.widget return? Is it just an HTML element? If so, then rendering chart in this way should work. If not, there may be some more steps you need to take before trying to render it.

Comment: this is complicated and somewhat intermediate to advanced... will require a somewhat big response